# Importing Betfair csv data to SQL Server and deploying the data to correct tables and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I'm working on my first database and have set up a structure and entered a few pieces of data so that I could test some queries on it. That's all fine but now I need to start importing data from csv files. I've been searching for help on this but not come up with anything that describes my exact situation.

The data files that I have are of the following format:

```
#File Header, 1.0
Home Team,Barnsley
Away Team,Wigan
Kick Off Time,14:02
Kick Off Date,03/08/2013
Home Goals,0
Away Goals,4
#File Data, 1.0
First Time Taken,Latest Time Taken,Market,Outcome,Odds,Number of Bets,Volume Matched,In Play
02/08/2013 20:38:53,03/08/2013 09:50:30,Correct Score,3 - 1,36,6,21.56,0
03/08/2013 14:04:24,03/08/2013 15:22:57,Over/Under 3.5 Goals,Over 3.5 Goals,3.65,4,58.04,1
03/08/2013 14:40:08,03/08/2013 15:03:09,Match Odds,The Draw,5,45,405.4,1
03/08/2013 13:20:37,03/08/2013 13:20:37,Half Time/Full Time,Draw/Wigan,5.7,2,5.24,0
03/08/2013 10:17:21,03/08/2013 10:17:37,DRAW NO BET,Wigan,1.56,5,35.98,0
03/08/2013 15:13:30,03/08/2013 15:13:30,2nd Goal,Barnsley,3.05,2,13.08,0
03/08/2013 14:21:33,03/08/2013 14:21:33,Over/Under 2.5 Goals,Over 2.5 Goals,2.64,2,7,1
03/08/2013 14:05:45,03/08/2013 14:31:10,Match Odds,Wigan,2.18,66,2775.8,1
03/08/2013 12:34:31,03/08/2013 13:26:26,Over/Under 2.5 Goals,Over 2.5 Goals,1.97,20,273.1,0
03/08/2013 15:30:14,03/08/2013 15:32:28,Over/Under 3.5 Goals,Over 3.5 Goals,4.9,10,118.36,1
03/08/2013 14:26:40,03/08/2013 14:29:43,Correct Score,0 - 0,6.8,12,278.96,1
03/08/2013 15:15:34,03/08/2013 15:27:39,Match Odds,Barnsley,110,7,8.86,1
```

I've seen some code examples that I think would work for the main section of the tabular data, but I also have the section at the top of the file with single values. I need all of the data in my database, and I also need to be able to enter the 'Competition' (League/Cup) as that info is not in the CSV. My csv's are sorted in folders by competition so it would be good if I could select a folder to import all csv's from and then enter the CompetitionID prior to import. The values in the first section of the csv need to go into my 'Match' table and the rest goes into the 'Data' table. I have MatchID as a Primary Key in 'Match' and as a Foreign Key in 'Data'.
Firstly, I'd like to ask if its a good idea to import the data to 'Test' tables first and then move it to the 'Live' tables? Or should I do this just to test the code and then import directly to the Live tables in future? Also, I'd be very grateful if somebody could offer me some guidance on how to get started with scripting the importing of data in this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting the above question I have been working hard on a solution. I have now been able to import individual CSV files and put the data in the 'Match' and 'Data' tables of my DB. I am also able to look up the Team ID from my 'Team' table and put that ID in the correct place with the data. This is my solution so far and I will try to update it as I improve the code. I feel that my approach may be somewhat convoluted due to being new to SQL programming, so if anybody can give any advice on making the code more efficient, that would be great:

```
USE BetfairFootballDB

CREATE TABLE #CSVTest_Data
(FirstTimeTaken DATETIME,
LatestTimeTaken DATETIME,
Market VARCHAR(50),
Outcome VARCHAR(50),
Odds DECIMAL,
NumberOfBets TINYINT,
VolumeMatched DECIMAL,
InPlay TINYINT)

CREATE TABLE #CSVTest_Match
(Header VARCHAR(50),
Data VARCHAR(50))

BULK
 INSERT #CSVTest_Data
FROM 'D:\Data\csvtest.csv' -- CSV file containing data
WITH
(
FIRSTROW =4,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

BULK
 INSERT #CSVTest_Match
FROM 'D:\Data\csvtest.csv' -- CSV file containing data
WITH
(
FIRSTROW =2,
LASTROW=7,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

----Check the content of the table.
--SELECT *
--FROM #CSVTest_Data

----Check the content of the table.
--SELECT *
--FROM #CSVTest_Match

------------------------------------

-- Convert imported CSV data from row data to column data
CREATE TABLE #temp1 (
    CompetitionID tinyint, 
    DateKickOff datetime, 
    TimeKickOff time(7),
    TeamIDHome tinyint, 
    TeamIDAway tinyint,
    TeamNameHome varchar(50), 
    TeamNameAway varchar(50), 
    ScoreHome tinyint, 
    ScoreAway tinyint,
)
--ALTER TABLE #temp1 ADD CONSTRAINT DF_CompetitionID DEFAULT 2 FOR CompetitionID;
ALTER TABLE #temp1 ADD DEFAULT 2 FOR CompetitionID --Set as default value that must be manually modified until I find a better way to specify this

INSERT INTO #temp1 (DateKickOff, TimeKickOff, TeamNameHome, TeamNameAway, ScoreHome, ScoreAway)
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Header, Data FROM #CSVTest_Match) AS T
PIVOT (Min(Data) FOR Header IN ([Kick Off Date], [Kick Off Time], [Home Team], [Away Team], [Home Goals], [Away Goals])) AS T2

CREATE TABLE #temp2 (
    TeamIDHome tinyint, 
    TeamIDAway tinyint, 
)
INSERT INTO #temp2 (TeamIDHome, TeamIDAway)
select HomeTeam.TeamID as TeamIDHome, AwayTeam.TeamID as TeamIDAway
from #temp1 as U
join BetfairFootballDB..Team as HomeTeam on U.TeamNameHome = HomeTeam.TeamName
join BetfairFootballDB..Team as AwayTeam on U.TeamNameAway = AwayTeam.TeamName

ALTER TABLE #temp1
DROP COLUMN TeamNameHome
ALTER TABLE #temp1
DROP COLUMN TeamNameAway

UPDATE #temp1
SET #temp1.TeamIDHome = #temp2.TeamIDHome 
FROM #temp2
UPDATE #temp1
SET #temp1.TeamIDAway = #temp2.TeamIDAway
FROM #temp2

INSERT INTO  BetfairFootballDB..Match --(CompetitionID, DateKickOff, TimeKickOff, TeamIDHome, TeamIDAway, ScoreHome, ScoreAway)
SELECT *
FROM #temp1

--Process Match END
-----------------------------------------------------------
--Process Data BEGIN

ALTER TABLE #CSVTest_Data ADD MatchID INT


update #CSVTest_Data
     Set MatchID = (SELECT TOP 1 MatchID FROM BetfairFootballDB..Match
                   ORDER BY MatchID DESC)


--This code should write the data to the Data table correctly once I have the MatchID column filled in the temp table
INSERT INTO  BetfairFootballDB..Data (MatchID, OddsFirstTimeTaken, OddsLastTimeTaken, MarketName, Outcome, Odds, NumberOfBets, VolumeMatched, InPlay)
SELECT MatchID, FirstTimeTaken, LatestTimeTaken, Market, Outcome, Odds, NumberOfBets, VolumeMatched, InPlay
FROM #CSVTest_Data


SELECT *
   FROM BetfairFootballDB..Match
SELECT *
   FROM BetfairFootballDB..Data
-------------------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp2
DROP TABLE #CSVTest_Data
DROP TABLE #CSVTest_Match
```